# How to set a DataGrid column to DatePicker input programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable, datepicker

There are a few of articles explaining how to make a specific column in your DataGrid [DatePickers](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/), [DatePickers](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/datepicker-in-datagrid-in-wpf/), or [DateTimePickers](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/03/wpf-datetimepicker-in-datagrid.html#.VL2Fj0fF_V4), but they all do it through XAML. Doing something like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

Is there a way to do in in C#?

I input a DataTable from a SQL database and bind it to a DataGrid. Like so:

```
dataGrid.DataContext = dataTable.AsDataView(); 
// or maybe dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView; 
// I'm not sure what the difference is
```

To my XAML that looks like this:

```
<DataGrid RowEditEnding="updateDatabase" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Visibility}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

</DataGrid>
```

I can go like this:

```
        dataTable.Rows[0][15] = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2);
```

or

```
        DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();
        dp.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
        dataTable.Rows[0][14] = dp;
```

But those just end up as date strings in the cell, not a DatePicker input type? Is there some way to do this? For instance

```
        dataTable.Columns[13].DataType.Equals(typeof(DatePicker));
        dataTable.Columns[13].DataType.Equals(typeof(DatePickerTextBox));
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

It'd also be okay if I could do it partially through XAML. For instance, if I make my XMAL:

```
<DataGrid RowEditEnding="updateDatabase" Name="taskTable" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,50,25,25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged_1">

    <!-- VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" -->
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Visibility}" />
        </Style>

    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="dates">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding dates}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>                    

</DataGrid>
```

The dates column from the the DataTable I load like so `taskTable.DataContext = dataTable.DefaultView;` Could I somehow get the dates columns to be the same one, with the data from the DataTable in C# under dates with the Template from XAML?

In this example, because the headers are the same, if I Select a Date in the left column, once I press enter it will go into the dates column on the right and be saved which is good. I just want them to be the same column though.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I might sound stupid, ... but why would you do this. MVVM's reason of existence is that you do not mess with UI elements in the code behind.

Comment: @user853710 No worries, I may be stupid for trying it. I didn't think there was a way to do it using XAML since the datatable is loaded in code, but I could be wrong.

Comment: There is a way. Before building the project the XAML is translated into C#. But it's not a good way to deal with any issues.

Comment: Okay, so I can put the `DataGridTemplateColumn` above in the datagrid before the rest of the columns are loaded from the database, how can I make that template apply to a specific column loaded by name?

Comment: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/

Comment: for a column you define a template. If none of the default suit your purpose you can expand it with a DataGridTemplateColumn. Inside of this you can add anything and bind it to anything

Comment: Yeah, I linked to that tutorial in my question. The problem is that I have a massive DataTable that's loaded from a SQL database, I'm not creating it myself and thus I can't turn off autogenerate and add them manually like that. At the moment I'm working on somethnig like this: `dataGrid.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["DateTemplate"];`

Comment: I never found it to be a good idea to to have it turned on. turn it off and you'll have more control. The amount of data loaded is not important. turn on the row virtualization and the binding in a backgroundworker. the performances will be brutal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of solutions for if you don't have to autogenerate the columns, but I had to allow for columns to be dynamically added and removed, so there was no way around it.

Here's what worked:

**C#**

Inside `public partial class MainWindow: window`

```
    public string [] dates = {"COLUMN NAMES", "THAT NEED", "TO BE DATES"};


    public void addColumnTemplates(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e){

        string header = e.Column.Header.ToString();

        if ( dates.Contains(header) )
        {
            MyDataGridTemplateColumn col = new MyDataGridTemplateColumn();
            col.ColumnName = e.PropertyName; 
            col.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("datePickerTemplate");
            e.Column = col;
            e.Column.Header = e.PropertyName;
        }

    }
```

Outside `public partial class MainWindow: window`

```
public class MyDataGridTemplateColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    public string ColumnName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override System.Windows.FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        ContentPresenter cp = (ContentPresenter)base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(cp, ContentPresenter.ContentProperty, new Binding(this.ColumnName));
        return cp;
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    public MyData(string name, bool data) { nameData = name; showData = data; }
    public string nameData { get; set; }
    public bool showData { get; set; }
}
```

**XMAL**

For datatemplate:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="datePickerTemplate">
            <DatePicker Text="{Binding}"
                ></DatePicker>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

And this is my XMAL for the datagrid

```
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                      AutoGeneratingColumn="addColumnTemplates">
            </DataGrid>
```

[image]